# Turning off RST

Tags: system-installation, rst

The instructions here [help.ubuntu.com/rst/](https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/) say navigate to iaStorAV in the Windows registry, but the screen shot shows iaStorV. On my new Dell desktop iaStorAV is empty.
In iaStorV Start is already 0, but deeper in StartOverride the entry named 0 is 0x00000003.

Can I assume

1. There's a typo
2. It's acceptable for Start to be already 0?

I think there's also a missing word here...
" you will need to turn RST in the computer’s BIOS."

Comment: see also: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347

Comment: I just discovered that too. Thanks.
It also doesn't say there are two possible scenarios and then list three ;-)

Comment: oldfred's tip pointed to a more accurate document. It still failed when rebooting after the regedits. But if you do a safe boot first, then boot to BIOS and change to AICH and finally boot normally, it works.

Comment: Since that link is not an answer here, and I do not have RST to know details, Please post exactly what you did and you can include the above link as reference. Then after a day or two you can accept your own answer so others can find this working example.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was as follows:

Follow the instructions [https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-installation-on-computers-with-intel-r-rst-enabled/15347](http://here), and ignore the fact that the two registry entries "start" were already 0.

Then

1. Boot the PC into windows safe mode ***after*** making changes to the
   registry.
2. Reboot the PC, go into the PC BIOS before it boots to  windows
3. Change the BIOS to ACHI mode
4. Reboot normally.

Only then did windows load the correct drivers.